# javascript get text from html input and use as value for another html input

Tags: javascript, html

i have 2 html text input so if in first one i put this link
https://example.com/E-LrapH4RtQ&list=PLy0zopi719kGIefv799akiQ7uh-8ntNXt

it will be
https://example.com/E-LrapH4RtQ

so now i want in second html input value to be **E-LrapH4RtQ**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function removeytb(string) {
        return string.split('&')[0];
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="ytburl" onblur="this.value=removeytb(this.value);" />
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the onblur from:

```
onblur="this.value=removeytb(this.value);"
```

to:

```
onblur="removeytb(this, 'name1');"
```

In order to get from *https://example.com/E-LrapH4RtQ* the last part you can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```
'https://example.com/E-LrapH4RtQ'.split('/').pop()
```

So:

```js
function removeytb(ele, secondInputName) {
  // set the value as before but using the element
  ele.value =  ele.value.split('&')[0];
  
  // get the last part from the ele splitting the string
  document.getElementsByName(secondInputName)[0].value = ele.value.split('/').pop();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ytburl" onblur="removeytb(this, 'name1');">


<input type="text" name="name1" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work `var link = www.example.com/idontknowthelink& some?stuff; var splitLink = link.split('&'); console.log(splitLink[0] + splitLink[1]);` you have the all link stocked in array then you do just change the src of the link

Comment: i put link manyally on  <input type="text" name="ytburl"   so it need to gets from there

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function removeytb(string) {
     var newUrl = string.split('&')[0];
     var name = newUrl.substr(newUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     document.getElementsByName("name1")[0].value = name
     return newUrl;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ytburl" onblur="this.value=removeytb(this.value);" />
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" />
```

Once you get the url, do a substring of it like below and set it to the element instead of splitting into array.

```
name = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a quick fix for what you are looking for!

The Function:

```
function useInput(InputValue,anotherInput)
  {
   InputValue =  InputValue.split('&')[1];
   if(!InputValue){InputValue='';}; //To avoid showing undefined
   document.getElementById(anotherInput).value=InputValue;
  }
```

The HTML

```
<input id="myInput" onKeyUp="useInput(this.value,'anotherInput')" value=""/>
<input id="anotherInput" type="input" value="" />
```

As the user types the input from the first field is captured, processed and placed as the value of the other input field (on the fly)!

Comment: the problem was in the ID for the second input, will update in a min.

Comment: Ok it works now.. i guess i will go ahead and add in the string splitting method myself also.. in a lil bit.

Comment: This solution is now fully working!  ...all issues fixed! =)